# Should you normalize your training data for Local Outlier Factor

Tags: outliers, normalization, localoutlierfactor

Say I'm using scikits implementation of Local Outlier Factor with euclidean distance being used by the reachability function. My input features are magnitudes apart, so is it advisable that I normalize my input features before training the function even though there might be several separate clusters.

Comment: This [research](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0152173) might be helpful to find an answer.

Answer (score 4):

That would be the recommended approach since Local Outlier Factors are based on Nearest Neighbor approach which is a similarity based algorithm. Normalization is recommended for most cases where similarity measures are used, unless you'd want high magnitude features to dominate the distance calculation. If you have a mixture of continuous, ordinal and binary variables in there, you may want to evaluate a few different scales for them.